# Why does a module type annotation in OCaml cause this code to not compile?

Tags: dictionary, module, ocaml, standard-library

I am working with the Map module in OCaml. Consider the following code to create a map with ints as keys:

```
module Int = struct
    type t = int
    let compare a b = a - b
end
 
module IntMap = Map.Make(Int)

let m = IntMap.(empty |> add 3 "hello")
```

This all works fine. It compiles and behaves as I would expect.

However, if I add a type annotation for the `Int` module so the top line becomes:

```
module Int : Map.OrderedType = struct
```

The final line causes an error in compilation:

```
let m = IntMap.(empty |> add 3 "hello")
                             ^
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         IntMap.key = Int.t
```

However `IntMap.key` and `Int.t` are both just an alias for `int`. Furthermore the `Int` module is of type `Map.OrderedType`. I know this because that's the required type for `Map.Make`.

So what an earth is going on here? Why would providing a type annotation that isn't necessary cause an error like this. Do type annotations cause stricter accessibility and not behave the same as inferred types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of annotation strictly limits the interface of a module. So it seems to me that with the added annotation the only things known about the key type of the map are as given by `Map.OrderedType`:

```
module type OrderedType =
    sig type t val compare : t -> t -> int end
```

This says nothing about the type `t` except that it exists and that it appears in the parameters of `compare`. In other words, you have hidden the fact that the type `t` (also known as `IntMap.key`) is the same type as `int`.

You can re-introduce this fact using `with`:

```
module Int : Map.OrderedType with type t = int = struct
    type t = int
    let compare a b = a - b
end
```